# How to do the max count part in SQL?

Tags: sql

I was told to Find out which occupation has the greatest number of patients with conditionID=MC8
I dk how to do the greatest part.....
Here my code right now

```
SELECT occupation
FROM Patient
WHERE EXISTS                  
(SELECT PatientID FROM PatientMedcon
    Where conditionID=’MC8’)    
GROUP BY occupation
HAVNG count(occupation) = (Select max(occupation)
From Patient
```

Comment: there seems to be one bracket missing, maybe more? [the one opened here `(Select max`]

Comment: And what problem are you facing ?

Comment: I am stuck at the how to show only the Occupation has the greatest number of patients. I can show the occupation which has the patient with MC8 condition ID.But i am stuck at the greatest part now

Comment: Because there some ocupation which has more than 1 patients. My second job here is to find out the Occupation which has the greatest number of patients with conditionID=MC8.

Answer (score 0):

You should approach these types of queries using regular joins and then add additional factors.  The following gets the count of patients for each occupation with that condition:

```
SELECT occupation, COUNT(*)
FROM Patient p JOIN
     PatentMedcon pm
     ON p.PatientId = pm.PatientId and
        pm.conditionId = 'MC8'
GROUP BY occupation
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

If you want the top row, that depends on the database.  It might be `select top 1`, `limit 1` at the end, `fetch first 1 rows only` at the end, or even something else.

Comment: I still can not do the top row part. i try limit 1 at the end at it doesnt work

Comment: @user3632007 . . . Please tag your question with the database you are using.  Different databases have different methods for doing this.

Comment: Patient(patientId, name, gender, DoB, address, state,postcode, homePhone, businessPhone, maritalStatus, occupation, duration,unit, race, registrationDate , GPNo, NaturopathNo) - PatientMedCon (patientId, conditionId, notes)  - MedicalCondition(conditionId, name)